# Can I store app data in online resources

Tags: android

My question is that, can I store my android app (that I created) data like High score on on-line source,  and when I click button it shows all the data (e.g. high scores), and how can I do this?

Comment: use web services to upload/download data online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.. You can store data to online. Use php and mysql .

**How to store in online database ?**
First send data using post or get method in android . Then insert data to mysql database using php.

**How to retrieve data from host ?**

Fetch data from database using php then encode to json .

**How to get data in app ?**

You can decode json url easily. Read more about 'json in android'

Answer (score 1):

if you creating a game app and you want to save data like high scores, simply you can use google leaderboard which offered by google play services sdk.

check this link, if you are interested how to implement it, look at links at end:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

and here is the home page:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/